# How to delete and update records using gridview from an xml file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I want to update and delete records by selecting the row of a gridview. This code is for adding the employee details.

```
 protected void Button_Add_Employee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDocument xmlEmloyeeDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlEmloyeeDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Employees.xml"));
            XmlElement ParentElement = xmlEmloyeeDoc.CreateElement("Employee");
            XmlElement ID = xmlEmloyeeDoc.CreateElement("ID");
            ID.InnerText = TextBox_Id.Text;
            XmlElement Name = xmlEmloyeeDoc.CreateElement("Name");
            Name.InnerText = TextBox_Name.Text;
            XmlElement Designation = xmlEmloyeeDoc.CreateElement("Designation");
            Designation.InnerText = TextBox_Desig.Text;

            ParentElement.AppendChild(ID);
            ParentElement.AppendChild(Name);
            ParentElement.AppendChild(Designation);

            xmlEmloyeeDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(ParentElement);
            xmlEmloyeeDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Employees.xml"));
            BindGrid();        
        }``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Just write code like this`
**For Updating:**

`protected void GridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/YourXmlFilePath"));
int iXmlRow = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(ViewState["gridrow"]));
ds.Tables[0].Rows[iXmlRow ]["Name"] = txtFirstName.Text;
ds.Tables[0].Rows[iXmlRow ]["Designation"] = txtLastName.Text;
.....
etc
ds.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/YourXMLPath"));
BindGrid();
}`

**For Deleting:**

`protected void GridView_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/YourXmlFilePath"));
ds.Tables[0].Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
ds.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/YourXmlFilePath"));
BindGrid();
}`

Hope this help...`